# Find position of value, that occurs only once in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have problem to find the best 'python way' to get back a position(row|column) of value in a pandas DataFrame.

I have a list of numbers... 
`list = [1,2,3,4,5,8]`

and a pandas Dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,8,8], 'B':[3,3,2,8],'x':[0.4,0.3,0.5,0.8]})

df
Out[2]: 
   A  B  x
0  1  3  0.4
1  3  3  0.3
2  8  2  0.5
3  8  8  0.8
```

1. I will compare the numbers from the list with the numbers in the DataFrame (['A'] and ['B']). In the end I want to know, which number in the list occurs in the DataFrame just once.

I would loop over the DataFrame with every number in the list, but I think this isn't the best python way.

2. I need the position of the once occurrences value in the DataFrame in the format (row|column), because if the single Number is in df['B'] then I need additional the value of df['A']. If the single Number is in df['A'] I need additional the value in df['B'],

I have no idea to solve this problem...I would be glad, if you have some keywords for searching so I can fix the problem.

Later I will copy the row, which includes the single numbers and the value behind the numbers in a new DataFrame.

The target is to get the following output...

```
dfnew

  SingleNumber AorB x
0 1            3    0.4           
1 2            8    0.5
```

I'm happy for every information to solve this problem. Let me know, if you need additional background information.

PS: I'm a beginner :)

Comment: The last row could also have been `5, 2, 0.5`, right? Because 5 also appears only once.

Comment: oh shit, that was a bad example of mine. I will edit my entry post.

Comment: But you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your starting point of (note I've renamed `list` to `data` otherwise it's shadowing the builtin):

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,8]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,8,8], 'B':[3,3,2,8],'x':[0.4,0.3,0.5,0.8]})
```

Firstly, flatten out your frame so that you have a single column to work with:

```
flattened = pd.melt(df, value_vars=['A', 'B'])
```

Which gives you:

```
  variable  value
0        A      1
1        A      3
2        A      8
3        A      8
4        B      3
5        B      3
6        B      2
7        B      8
```

Then filter for the values that are in `data` (in this case it returns the same dataframe, so I won't copy/paste the same result as above):

```
in_data = flattened[flattened.value.isin(data)]
```

Then drop *all* duplicate values:

```
only_once = in_data.drop_duplicates(subset='value', keep=False)
```

Which gives you:

```
  variable  value
0        A      1
6        B      2
```

Then you can use the index on that to get back to your original DF:

```
new_df = df.iloc[only_once.index // len(df.columns)]
```

Which gives you:

```
   A  B    x
0  1  3  0.4
2  8  2  0.5
```

Then assign the column...

```
new_df['single_number'] = only_once.value.values
```

And the end result is:

```
   A  B    x  single_number
0  1  3  0.4              1
2  8  2  0.5              2
```

This maintains your original index values, if you really want new ones, then look at `.reset_index(drop=True)` to get 0 and 1 instead.

---

Smarter way of getting the original data back after the following comment:

> For example...let me change the df to `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,8,5], 'B':[3,3,2,8],'x':[0.4,0.3,0.5,0.8]})`. When I compute the `new_df` I get a wrong result.

Note this doesn't include checking the values against the list.

Flatten the columns with a reset index so it's a column available for later and drop all the duplicated values from it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,8,5], 'B':[3,3,2,8],'x':[0.4,0.3,0.5,0.8]})
unique = pd.melt(
    df.reset_index(), 
    id_vars='index', 
    value_vars=['A', 'B'],
    value_name='SingleNumber'
).drop_duplicates(subset='SingleNumber', keep=False)
```

Which gives you:

```
   index variable  value
0      0        A      1
3      3        A      5
6      2        B      2
```

Then merge it back with your original frame using its index and the index column retained previously.

```
new_df = df.merge(unique, left_index=True, right_on='index')
```

You end up with:

```
   A  B    x  index variable  SingleNumber
0  1  3  0.4      0        A             1
6  8  2  0.5      2        B             2
3  5  8  0.8      3        A             5
```

Then drop or rename columns or reset index etc... as required.

Comment: This is a nice solution for my problem. I think I will try to find an other way to get `new_df`, because the values can stand in every line in a bigger DataFrame. So I try to forestall a wrong result, because of the division.

Comment: @EnergyNet sorry - I'm not sure I'm quite following where your concern about the division is?

Comment: For example...let me change the df to `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,8,5], 'B':[3,3,2,8],'x':[0.4,0.3,0.5,0.8]})`. When I compute the `new_df` I get a wrong result.

Comment: @EnergyNet oops... I'll have a think on that :)

Comment: No Problem :) Thank you so much for your help. This Problem I will hopefully fix by myself...

Comment: @EnergyNet I've updated the answer to include a (hopefully) smarter way - let me know if there's any probs.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution but not much time to explain:

```
dfnew = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,8], columns=['SingleNumber'])

def func(row):
    match = df_values[df_values == row['SingleNumber']]
    if len(match) == 1:
        idx = match.index.get_level_values(0)[0]
        col = match.index.get_level_values(1)[0]
        return pd.Series({
                'AorB': df.loc[idx, 'A' if col == 'B' else 'B'], 
                'x': df.loc[idx, 'x']
            })

dfnew.join(dfnew.apply(func, axis=1)).dropna()
```

Please let me know if anything needs explaining!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but I get an value error(Other Series must have a name). Do you have an idea, what I'm doing wrong? I don't realy understand, what you are doing in line 4. `match = df_values[df_values == x['SingleNumber']]`

Comment: `match` holds the number of times where `df_values` match the value of `x` (which iterates over your list).

Comment: I don't understand what you are comparing in `match`. you say a DataFrame is equal to a Series, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, when you apply the function `func` (by `axis=1`), what is passed to the function (which I misleadingly called `x`) is a row of the dataframe. So here, `x` is a series, and `x['SingleNumber']` is the value of `SingleNumber` at the current row. Note that `apply` iterates on rows (or columns if `axis=0`).

Comment: I renamed the variable `x` to `row`. The name was left over from another attempt...

Comment: Okay, Sorry, now I understand. Unfortunately, it doesn't run.